# Ubuntu Studio 23.04 (uses KDE/Plasma) - clock in panel "stuck" after waking up from hibernation, other panel glitches

Tags: kde, plasma, clock

Have been using Ubuntu Studio 23.04 beta for a couple of months now, really like it. There are a few bugs with it however.

- One of them is that the clock in the panel (by default on top of the screen in Ubuntu Studio) stays "stuck" at the time of hibernation and keeps displaying this time until the process is killed (logout, reboot, kill/replace widget).
- Also, there are sometimes other glitches with the panel's "notification" icons, like spacing being off or some of them disappearing.

I know the kernel has the correct time after resuming from hibernation because typing "date" in a terminal window displays it.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 is a *released product*, with Ubuntu *mantic* being the *alpha* or *beta* product, and it being renamed from Ubuntu *mantic* to Ubuntu 23.04 when it reached RC status (what follows *beta*).  If you're still using the *beta* then please upgrade packages asap as that is likely your issue, otherwise you're using Ubuntu Studio 23.04 and not a *beta* thus question needs editing.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/04/20/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-released/